# Can jQuery remove this text?

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, dom

I'm trying to find a work around to remove the "by" line from the Announcements Summary View on a SharePoint 2007 site.  For various reasons, nothing I find on the web seems to be working - so I want to take another route, provided some talented-kind-soul will help.  Does anyone know how to make jQuery work some magic so the first block of HTML can end up rendering as the second block of HTML?

Block 1:

```
<a onfocus="OnLink(this)" href="/Lists/Our%20Announcements/DispForm.aspx?ID=36" ONCLICK="GoToLink(this);return false;" target="_self">Title of Annoucement  </a><IMG SRC="/_layouts/1033/images/new.gif" alt="New">&nbsp;</span><br>by <nobr><span><A ONCLICK="GoToLink(this);return false;" HREF="/_layouts/userdisp.aspx?ID=2258">Lastname, FirstName I.</A><img border="0" height="1" width="3" src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" alt="" /><a href="javascript:" onclick="IMNImageOnClick();return false;" class="ms-imnlink"><img title="" alt="No presence information" name="imnmark" border="0" valign="middle" height="12" width="12" src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" sip="email@address.com" id="imn0,type=smtp" ></a></span></nobr></td><td width=20% align="right" nowrap class="ms-vb">&nbsp;4/15/2013 12:51 PM</td></tr><tr><td colspan=2 class="ms-vb"> <div id="{291345DC-BEAE-47B6-8F53-41C07838090C}36"><div class=ExternalClass5BF6EE28A88D436CAC2FE553E7F2CED7><div>
```

Block 2:

```
<a onfocus="OnLink(this)" href="/Lists/Our%20Announcements/DispForm.aspx?ID=36" ONCLICK="GoToLink(this);return false;" target="_self">Title of Annoucement  </a><IMG SRC="/_layouts/1033/images/new.gif" alt="New">&nbsp;</span></td><td width=20% align="right" nowrap class="ms-vb">&nbsp;4/15/2013 12:51 PM</td></tr><tr><td colspan=2 class="ms-vb"> <div id="{291345DC-BEAE-47B6-8F53-41C07838090C}36"><div class=ExternalClass5BF6EE28A88D436CAC2FE553E7F2CED7><div>
```

This is what I need to have removed:

```
<br>by <nobr><span><A ONCLICK="GoToLink(this);return false;" HREF="/_layouts/userdisp.aspx?ID=2258">Lastname, FirstName I.</A><img border="0" height="1" width="3" src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" alt="" /><a href="javascript:" onclick="IMNImageOnClick();return false;" class="ms-imnlink"><img title="" alt="No presence information" name="imnmark" border="0" valign="middle" height="12" width="12" src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" sip="email@address.com" id="imn0,type=smtp" ></a></span></nobr>
```

----------------------------Update for better formatting-------------------------------
There really isn't anything that I can see for which jQuery can select on.  Also, this is coming from SharePoint, so I can't add any id's or div's to the generated code.

Block 1:

```
    <TR>
      <TD width=80% class="ms-vb" style="padding-bottom: 3px">
        <span class="ms-announcementtitle"><a onfocus="OnLink(this)" href="/Lists/Our%20Announcements/DispForm.aspx?ID=36" ONCLICK="GoToLink(this);return false;" target="_self">Title of Annoucement  </a><IMG SRC="/_layouts/1033/images/new.gif" alt="New">&nbsp;</span>
        <br>by 
        <nobr>
            <span><A ONCLICK="GoToLink(this);return false;" HREF="/_layouts/userdisp.aspx?ID=2258">Lastname, FirstName I.</A><img border="0" height="1" width="3" src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" alt="" /><a href="javascript:" onclick="IMNImageOnClick();return false;" class="ms-imnlink"><img title="" alt="No presence information" name="imnmark" border="0" valign="middle" height="12" width="12" src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" sip="email@address.com" id="imn0,type=smtp" ></a></span>
        </nobr>
      </td>
      <td width=20% align="right" nowrap class="ms-vb">&nbsp;4/15/2013 12:51 PM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=2 class="ms-vb"> 
            <div id="{291345DC-BEAE-47B6-8F53-41C07838090C}36">
            <div class=ExternalClass5BF6EE28A88D436CAC2FE553E7F2CED7>
            <div>
            <div>
                <p style="line-height:normal;margin:0in 0in 0pt;vertical-align:top" class=MsoNormal>
                    <b>
                        <span style="font-family:'Arial','sans-serif';color:black;font-size:9pt">
                            <em>A message from Firstname Lastname</em>
                        </span>
                    </b>
                </p>
                <p style="line-height:normal;margin:0in 0in 0pt;vertical-align:top" class=MsoNormal>
                    <span style="font-family:'Arial','sans-serif';color:black;font-size:9pt"></span> 
                </p>
                <p style="line-height:normal;margin:0in 0in 0pt;vertical-align:top" class=MsoNormal>
                    <span style="font-family:'Arial','sans-serif';color:black;font-size:9pt">Here is the message </span>
                </p>
                <p style="line-height:normal;margin:0in 0in 0pt;vertical-align:top" class=MsoNormal>
                    <span style="font-family:'Arial','sans-serif';color:black;font-size:9pt"></span> 
                </p>
                <p style="line-height:normal;margin:0in 0in 0pt;vertical-align:top" class=MsoNormal>
                    <span style="font-family:'Arial','sans-serif';color:black;font-size:9pt">To...
            </div>
        </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD>
            <font size=1>&nbsp;</font>
        </TD>
    </TR>
```

Block 2:

```
     <TR>
      <TD width=80% class="ms-vb" style="padding-bottom: 3px">
        <span class="ms-announcementtitle"><a onfocus="OnLink(this)" href="/Lists/Our%20Announcements/DispForm.aspx?ID=36" ONCLICK="GoToLink(this);return false;" target="_self">Title of Annoucement  </a><IMG SRC="/_layouts/1033/images/new.gif" alt="New">&nbsp;</span>
      </td>
      <td width=20% align="right" nowrap class="ms-vb">&nbsp;4/15/2013 12:51 PM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=2 class="ms-vb"> 
            <div id="{291345DC-BEAE-47B6-8F53-41C07838090C}36">
            <div class=ExternalClass5BF6EE28A88D436CAC2FE553E7F2CED7>
            <div>
            <div>
                <p style="line-height:normal;margin:0in 0in 0pt;vertical-align:top" class=MsoNormal>
                    <b>
                        <span style="font-family:'Arial','sans-serif';color:black;font-size:9pt">
                            <em>A message from Firstname Lastname</em>
                        </span>
                    </b>
                </p>
                <p style="line-height:normal;margin:0in 0in 0pt;vertical-align:top" class=MsoNormal>
                    <span style="font-family:'Arial','sans-serif';color:black;font-size:9pt"></span> 
                </p>
                <p style="line-height:normal;margin:0in 0in 0pt;vertical-align:top" class=MsoNormal>
                    <span style="font-family:'Arial','sans-serif';color:black;font-size:9pt">Here is the message </span>
                </p>
                <p style="line-height:normal;margin:0in 0in 0pt;vertical-align:top" class=MsoNormal>
                    <span style="font-family:'Arial','sans-serif';color:black;font-size:9pt"></span> 
                </p>
                <p style="line-height:normal;margin:0in 0in 0pt;vertical-align:top" class=MsoNormal>
                    <span style="font-family:'Arial','sans-serif';color:black;font-size:9pt">To...
            </div>
        </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD>
            <font size=1>&nbsp;</font>
        </TD>
    </TR>
```

Comment: You should format the code so that it's easy to look!

Comment: Are there any surrounding elements with classes or ids that let you identify the right elements to target?

Comment: I've updated my answer.  If the word `by` is always inside a `td` in this case you can search for the `td's` with that word and only replace those OR you can just do the replace on the entire body if you want.  Just depends on your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this to remove it though it might help to know what is wrapping it so you don't remove something by accident that needs to remain. In my example I've just placed a div around the culprit:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/yyEXU/1/

Code:

```
$('div').html($('div').html().replace('by',''))
```

Or you can use body or document to be more universal:

```
$('body').html($('body').html().replace('by',''));
```

Since the `td's` contain the by You could optimize this and look for the word `by` and only do the replace on those if you want:

```
$('td').each(function() {
  if ($(this).text().indexOf('by')>-1) 
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace('by',''));
    $('nobr', this).remove();  // if the nobr contains by we remove this.
     // $(this).empty()  // this will remove the contents and keep the tags.
}
```

Comment: Will your solution remove the persons name too?  I need everything in between the `<nobr>` tags to be removed too.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood.. Do you want the nobr tags removed as well?  I add code to remove the tags and/or remove their contents.

Comment: Yes, the whole entire line marked "This is what I need to have removed:" (not meant to be mean in any way).  Thank you for you help, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
$('.ms-partline').parent().parent().parent().remove();
```

It will only delete ones that are views in sharepoint